# Smartscroll not stopping at the right place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, smooth-scrolling

I'm currently creating my own portfolio but i have a hard time fixing a problem.

I did use this jquery code for smoothscroll:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
            if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
              var target = $(this.hash);
              target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
              if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                  scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
              }
        }
    });
});
```

And the menu bar i did use this to scroll to a part of my page:

```
<a href="#skills">Skills<a/>
```

and scrolling smooth to the place I create this:

```
<div id="Skills"></div>
```

its working. In my website i used a position:fixed; for my menu so it will scroll with me.

When I use 
`<div id="Skills"></div>`
 i get a part of the text it has to show under (behind) the menu bar.

When I use  higher in the code it still wont get on the right place.

You can see this as an example: http://soziev.com/
As you can see it stops at the right place, mine does stop under (behind) the menu bar
Can you help me with this problem?

Comment: `When I use my i get a part of the text` please fix this

Comment: Without showing us you relevent html and css I can't tell what is your issue. But there is a high probability that your div `#skills` doesn't start where you think it starts. check with inspect element where the div starts.

Comment: @Claudiu Hey i had trouble with pasting my html and css codes in here. so i did put it on pastebin http://pastebin.com/MPD30WsL

Comment: Probably just need to add `body { padding-top: height-of-menu; }`

Comment: @brian Thanks for  your answer but not working :( Keeps staying under menu bar

Comment: pastebin not a good idea. jsfiddle would help us

Comment: @Claudiu hey there, done. http://jsfiddle.net/Cessum/pmaefrjo/ Maybe this is a better explenation: Click on creaties and see its scrolling down. There you can see its not stopping on the red square. its scrolling little further.

Comment: If you see in the fiddle, clicking on creaties goes where it should go. probably it is a postion issue with the skills div

Comment: @Claudiu Hey there, no it does not. Could you open the fiddle link? if you have done that click on creaties and go to element inspect and remove the menu bar. You can see there that there is red color behind it. But i want it to stop before it gets to red.